# i am loading webview on starting of my application

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am loading a web view on the startup of my application. 
But before that I am loading a splash screen and I want to show the splash screen until the web view is fully loaded. 
How can I do that? 
I am working in Android Studio.

Comment: in your WebView Client "onPageStarted" show your Splash Image and "onPageFinished"  hide your splash image

Answer (score 2):

You can hide your splash screen when your webpage load complicated using webview client

```
 mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

   public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        // hide your splash screen
    }
});
```

Comment: > hey bro i think u didnt read the queston properly. i want to show splash screen till webview is fully loaded in background.

Comment: where you mention that your webview is loaded on background

Answer (score 0):

Do like this...

```
  public class SItemsWebView extends ActionBarActivity {
        private WebView webView;   
        private String url;


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_subject_list_items_in_web_view);
            this.initViews();      
            loadWebView(url);
             }

        //initializes all views
        private void initViews() {
            webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.filesWebView);
        }   

        //show Url in WebView
        public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient {
            @JavascriptInterface
            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
               //show your splash scree here
            }

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                // hide your splash image here
                }
            }
        }


        public void loadWebView(String url) {
            webView.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
            webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
            webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
            webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);                
            webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            webView.loadUrl(url);
        }               

    }
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestions. i tried and its still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap icon) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, icon);
            //show your splash scree here
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            // hide your splash screen
        }
    });
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestions. i tried and its still not working